# Where Statement w/ Distinct

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a large table but for the purposes of this question, let's assume I have the follwoing column strucure:

[image]

I'd like to have a Where statement that returns only rows where the e-mail address is distinct in that particular column.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most databases, you can do this

```
select t.AccountId, t.BillingEmail
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by BillingEmail) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can get as many columns as you like from the table.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT BillingEMail
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY BillingEMail
HAVING COUNT(BillingEMail) = 1
```

OR `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b30/2)

I don't know what RDBMS you are using (*the reason why i can't introduce of using analytical functions*) but you can do this by joining with a subquery if you want to get all columns

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   tableName a
       INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT BillingEMail
        FROM   tableName
        GROUP  BY BillingEMail
        HAVING COUNT(BillingEMail) = 1 
      )b ON a.BillingEMail = b.BillingEMail
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b30/4)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer JW's approach, but here is another one using NOT EXISTS.

```
SELECT AccountID, [Billing Email]
FROM   table t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    -- Make sure that no other row contains the same
    -- email, but a different Account ID.
    SELECT 1
    FROM   table t2
    WHERE  t1.[Billing Email] = t2.[Billing Email]
    AND    t1.AccountID <> t2.AccountID
)
```